# Error importing JSON file into LUIS List entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am following the suggested LUIS syntax when importing a file, but throws an error "A valid json file is required". I am not sure what it does not like about the file. I even tried a truncated file, and it does not like it. Here is complete content of my file:

```html
[
  {
    "canonicalForm": "4214441",
    "list": [
      "SHASTA COUNTY RISK MANAGEMENT REDDING"
    ]
  },
  {
    "canonicalForm": "4476278",
    "list": [
      "SEDGWICK UC 14533 SAN DIEGO"
    ]
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: The json should be like https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c09

Comment: The link you have provided is irrelevant to the question. It is related to uploading and labeling utterances whereas the question pertains to uploading of list based entities using a json file. The json text I have noted in my question does conform to the json schema noted in the "Import New Entities" section of LUIS

Answer (score 3):

The contents of your file looks fine, but from your screenshot, it looks like the file extension used is `.txt`.  Change your file extension to `.json`, eg. `insuranceco.json`.